# Looping through List of nested List of lists

Tags: python

I have a nested list of lists occurring in the form of

```
 A = [[a,b],[c,d]] or [[[a,b],[c,d]]] or [[[[a,b],[c,d]]]] or [[[[[a,b],[c,d]]]]]
```

and so on. These forms of `A` don't occur at the same time.

How can I code to peel the list, no matter how nested A may be, and obtain only:

```
[a,b] 
[c,d]
```

I tried this:

```
def Peel_list(Features):
    try:
        for lon,lat in Features:
            print((lon,lat))
    except:
        for Feature in Features:
            for t_list in Feature:
                for A in t_list:
                    for lon,lat in A:
                        print((lon,lat))
    return()
```

But it only works for limited A.

Comment: You can [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) and then build your final result

Comment: Are you guaranteed to always have lists as the inner element? Never like `[[[a], b, [c, d]]]`?

Comment: possibly not an answer . . . can you flatten the list as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists/952946#952946 and then extract [lon, lat] data as pairs of numbers in the generated simple list? (pull out sequential pairs of numbers a, b then c,d then e,f etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when we want to deal with a problem of arbitrarily nested objects recursion is a good place to start. Here we want to keep "digging down" until we hit the base case, in our case any non list value. The code looks something like this

```
test = [1, [3,4],[[5]], [[[6]]]]
peeled = []

def peel(myList, peeled):
    for val in myList:
        if isinstance(val, list):
            if not isinstance(val[0], list):
                peeled.append(val)
            else:
                peel(val, peeled)
        else:
            peeled.append(val)


peel(test, peeled)
print(peeled)
```

This will give you something like

> [1, [3, 4], [5], [6]]

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach for the cases that you've provided would be to have a while-loop that continually checks if the size of the list is 1 and modifies your list to contain only the single element (this would get rid of the outermost list).

```
x = [[[[[a,b],[c,d]]]]]
while len(x) == 1:
    x = x[0]

// result is x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

The general approach for when you have elements nested in an arbitrary number of lists would be Mitchel's answer.

Comment: This doesnt work for me using the test case `[1, [3,4],[[5]], [[[6]]]]`

Comment: Actually on a second read I think I made this problem more complicated than OP intended it to be. This should work for his cases

Comment: This will however fail on something like `[[[[[1]]]]]`

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

you can also try [numpy ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) function on your list, output will be a 1D array.

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate

Comment: Is the result is what you were asking for? because it is going to be a 1D array at the end with ravel(), instead of the 2D array, maintaining the inner most array structures..

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recursion based solution:

```
l1 = [[[['a','b'],['c','d'], [[1,2]]]]]
l2 = [[[[['a','b'],['c','d']]]]]

def f(inp):
    # you can skip this if statement if you are sure that there is no empty nested list 
    if not inp:
        return [[]]
    if (all(isinstance(element, list) for element in inp)):
        return [elem for x in inp for elem in f(x)]
    else:
        return [inp]
```

With `all()`, a condition can be checked on every element of an iterable.
Results would be:

```
f(l1) #[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], [1, 2]]
f(l2) #[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], []]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def flatten(d):
   if all(not isinstance(i, list) for i in d):
      yield d
   else:
      for i in d:
         yield from flatten(i)

print(list(flatten([[[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]]]])))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate